# How to use AutoLayout to make dynamic constraint in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I set a tableviewcell in storyboard and add basic constraints with  all widget,Now I get data from the server and have a key called type in data, According to the type,I will change the widget(change position,hidden) in tableviewcell ,so I need set constraint dynamiclly ,What shall I do for the best way?

This is the constraints I set in storyboard

[image]!

[image]

This is the result that I want to achieve

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Make constraints outlets and set it depends on data type.

Comment: Add height constraints and connect them as outlets. You then can change the constant of that constraint to 0 to basically remove the item from beeing displayed.